# go install but unable to run app from folders uther than bin

Tags: go

On a mac computer I set the export `export GOPATH=$(pwd)`.

`go install` is running fine and the bin folder contains the app, but I am unable to run the app/binary?

Comment: We can only guess what you did. Provide us with a reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Further, you should have a single GOPATH (don't set it dynamically). vendor your dependencies using gvt or gb, rather than trying to fight GOPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`go install` installs a binary to `$GOPATH/bin` which is likely does not present in `PATH` env variable of your OS.

You need to add`$GOPATH/bin` to your `PATH`:

```
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```